# How to remove a file with weird name on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My colleague accidentally created a file named `U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;.png` on AWS S3.

[image]

How can I remove it?

Here are what I have tried:

1. Using aws cli:

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;&#xf;.png                                       <aws:bionime>
[2] 93550
➜  ~ delete: s3://bucket-name/U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39                                                                                                                        <aws:bionime>

[2]    93550 done       aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39
```

After this operation, the file can still be seen with AWS console on S3 .

2. Clicking *Actions* -> *Delete* using AWS console:

This operation results in a success operation, but the file is still there.

[image]

When I click on the file, there's a message saying `An unexpected error occurred.`. I don't know where to find further information about this error.

[image]

There's another file named `U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39.png` inside the same path in the S3 bucket.

When I run `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`, I find two files named `U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39.png`.

```
2019-08-22 08:06:41       1480 U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39.png
2019-08-22 09:13:37       1545 U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39.png
```

Anyone knows how to delete this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little Python3 script that will delete an object based on its **ETag** (as displayed in the S3 console):

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
ETAG = 'a3271a215a4fb28aa3bf2f55173af3f2'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2') # Change as appropriate

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET)

for object in response['Contents']:
    if object['ETag'].strip('"') == ETAG:
        print('Deleting ', object['Key'])
        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=object['Key'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I have replicated the scenario and was able to successfully delete the file using below command :

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/U00d89db4dc52b87f205fb151f6225b39\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;\&#xf\;.png
```

You just need to replace the '& with \&' and '; with \;'. The backslash ( \ ) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

Comment: Adding \ character doesn't work in my case. This is strange.